# Redirect from apache rewrite

Tags: apache, wordpress

I want to redirect

/na to /na.php

Now, I'm using wordpress and I don't want to create page from wordpress. So, I add

RewriteRule ^na$ /na.php

but it's not working. How should I write it ?

I updated like following but still no luck

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^na$ /na.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]


</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^na$ /na.php [L]
```

The first argument for the RewriteRule omits the leading slash, and if you don’t check for the exact string you’ll run into an infinite loop. The `[L]` prevents further processing of the request.

Comment: Put the rule for na.php before the other rules.

Comment: not working ... but RewriteRule ^na\.$ /na.php is working .. I can call na. . I only want na without . =(

Comment: working fine ... after I change file name. na.php to redirect_na.php